# namespace prefix for childelements in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, parent-child, xml-namespaces

I'm currently learning XML and have arrived at the wonderfull world of XML Schema used with multiple namespaces.

My question is when I should and do not have to declare a namespace prefix.

Consider the following snippet of XML Schema:

```
<A:schema   xmlns:A="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="B" 
        xmlns:B="B" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <A:element name="foo">
        <complexType>                   <!-- or A:complexType?-->
            <element name="bar" type="B:myType"/>       <!-- or A:element?-->
        </complexType>
    </A:element>

    <B:complexType name="myType">
        <choice>                         <!--or B:choice?-->
            <element name="baz" type="string"/>      <!--or B:element?-->
            <element name="bas" type="string"/>      <!--or B:element?-->
        </choice>
    </B:complexType>

</A:schema>
```

Do I have to specify the namespace prefix on all the child nodes of a node with a namespace prefix, or is this inherited? Alternatively is `A:complexType` different from `complexType` when it's parent node had the A namespace prefix attached to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *binding* of prefixes to namespace URIs is inherited by child elements but the elements themselves are not automatically placed in the same namespace as their parent.  If they were there would be no way to express an element in a namespace with a child that is *not* in a namespace.  In your example, all the elements that are part of the schema definition need to be in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace (which is conventionally mapped to either the `xsd` or `xs` prefix):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="urn:B" 
        xmlns:B="urn:B" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="bar" type="B:myType"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="myType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="bas" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The exception is when you use `xmlns="..."` which defines the default namespace for elements with no prefix, e.g.

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
   <element ...>
      <complexType ...>
```

is equivalent to

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...>
   <xs:element ...>
      <xs:complexType ...>
```

The `type="B:myType"` is correct, as it is referring to the type named `myType` in the `targetNamespace` of the schema, which you have in turn mapped to the prefix `B`.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how the namespaces work here.  The `<xs:complexType name="myType">` element (in the XMLSchema namespace) is an instruction to the schema to declare a type named `myType` in the `targetNamespace` of the schema (i.e. `urn:B`).  So to say that an element should be of type `{urn:B}myType` you map a prefix (`B`) to this namespace URI and then say `<xs:element type="B:myType"/>`.